# terminal defaults to old yarn version (lerna bootstrap)

Tags: yarnpkg, lerna

I don't think this is an issue specific to lerna, I actually think it is nvm related (though I commented out nvm from my .bash_profile to test that, without success).

I'm trying to `lerna bootstrap` but it keeps using (and failing) an older version (1.3.2) of yarn than what I'm running:

```sh
$ yarn -v
1.22.4

$ lerna bootstrap
info cli using local version of lerna
lerna notice cli v3.22.1
lerna info versioning independent
lerna info bootstrap root only
yarn install v1.3.2
error An unexpected error occurred: "patterns.map is not a function".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
lerna ERR! yarn install --mutex network:42424 --non-interactive exited 1 in 'root'
lerna ERR! yarn install --mutex network:42424 --non-interactive exited 1 in 'root'

$ yarn -v
1.22.4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rooted around in my filesystem and removed `~/.yarn` and `~/node_modules/yarn` and everything works now.

Answer (score 1):

For me, this was happening in `Ubuntu 20.04`, and it solved with unistalling cmdtest:

```
sudo apt-get purge cmdtest
```

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade yarn. I use brew so I used `brew install yarn` and it worked.